# Make index function in Excel work like in Sheets

Tags: excel

I can't seem to find a way to replicate Sheets' approach on no row and no column argument in Excel (it says not enough arguments)
For instance, with `=INDEX(A1:A10)` , Sheets will print the whole range [like shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L16hn.gif)

Is there a way to replicate this in Excel ?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to return the array, why not just `=A1:A10`?

Comment: Because I need the cells to be values and not functions, which is why I wanted to do it like on Sheets because it simply copies the values of indexed range

Comment: I don't believe it does that. If it did, you'd be able to delete a cell, and Sheets does not allow you to delete an individual cell in a `SPILL'd` array.  Excel doesn't allow that either, but pops up a warning if you try.  If your version of Excel doesn't SPILL arrays, then you'd have to enter it as an array formula over the relevant range.

Comment: I maybe poorly explained but you can see in the GIF I linked above the way it works on Sheets and this is what I want to achieve in Excel

Comment: Works the same in my version of Excel, with either `=A1:A10` or `=index(a1:a10,)`  or with the formula entered as an array across B1:B10, which is what you will need to do if your version of Excel does not "SPILL"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

=INDEX(A1:A10, )

That works for me in Excel365, not sure it'll work in earlier versions.

If the range argument has multiple columns you can use this.

=INDEX(A1:B10,,)

In fact it probably makes sense to use that no matter the no of columns/rows in the range.

Comment: I just tested it an you are right, it works on Excel 365. But I am using Excel 2019 ...

Comment: So it didn't work in Excel 2019? What happens, in Excel 2019, if you array enter the formula?

Comment: Odly enough it just prints the first item in the range

Comment: For Excel2019 it will not spill all elements of array automatically. You have to specify row and columns to retrieve array element one by one. Only Excel365 has that automatic spill behaviour.